# is there a way to create a one on one video call without the use of media server?

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, p2p, video-capture

I've been looking around the net if this has been done. I've seen an HTML5 application but it seems that only few browsers support this. I've also seen the one created by Ericsson but it was way back 2010-2011.

Technically, what I wanted to ask if there was a script already or tutorial that supports a one on one video call without using a media server. Thanks.